# Why can't I connect QWebsocket::error SIGNAL to a lambda or any other SLOT type with identical signature? QT5.9

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.9, qtwebsockets

I'm trying to build a simple program that implements a QWebSocket, however, what I first tried to do is check if the connection is enabled. It didn't throw any exception since I never connected the error signal but I could check on my cloud server if any connection attempt had been made and saw that a connection never happened. So I tried to implement the error signal to see what the cause of the problem is, but I can't seem to make the signal connect to my printing function. I mean I always get a compile time error. If someone has any idea on how I should approach this, please say it!

I've tried like this also. I don't get any compile time errors however I get this runtime error:

```
QObject::connect(websocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)),cp, SLOT(OnWebSocketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)));
```

Below are 3 images to illustrate the problem:

Main file:
[image: image 1]

The error message:
[image: image 2]

CustomPrinter class:
[image: image 3]

Also ignote the "qDebug()<<""<error();" line it's commented now.

THis is the error I'm getting"

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QWebSocket::error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error) in ../Websocket1/main.cpp:14"
```

Comment: As the error says, remove the `&` in front of `websocket` in the connect

Comment: use `connect(webSocket, QOverload<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>::of(&QWebSocket::error), this, &CustomPritner::OnWebSocketError);`

Comment: I can't use "this" keyword in the main function context

Comment: @ionutgeorgesoran then use `connect(webSocket, QOverload<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>::of(&QWebSocket::error), cp, &CustomPritner::OnWebSocketError);`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros you must not name the arguments, just their types.

This is wrong:

```
QObject::connect(websocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)),cp, SLOT(OnWebSocketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)));
```

This is correct:

```
QObject::connect(websocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),cp, SLOT(OnWebSocketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
```

Also it's best to not use the macros but the new syntax accepting function pointers, this way it does some compile time checks.

```
QObject::connect(websocket, &QWebSocket::error, cp, &CustomPritner::OnWebSocketError);
```

Remember that you must always use `QObject*` as arguments otherwise it won't compile.